# Add rows in Table layout in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2, tabular

I am new to ExtJS. I am looking to add rows in table layout (Not in grid). I have searched in website that shown the examples of Grid. Can anyone help me to add rows in table layout?

Following the code I have used to create a table layout.

```
            title: 'TestTable',
            layout:{
                type: 'table',
                columns: 2
            },
            defaults: { width:100, height: 200},
            items:[{
                title:'Test'
            },{
                title:'Test2'
            }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout by definition lays out components added under container, so just add another component to panel and new row will be created.

Example:

```
panel.add({
    title: 'Another test'
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JH2HF/